# Merge several list in SharePoint 2010

Tags: merge, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I have trivial question and I saw the same questions here and there in the Internet. However, it doesn't work in my code.

let me explain the issue:
I have very old SharePoint (2013 or even 2010). And there are bunch of lists with identical columns. I want to merge them into one common list.

What I've tried already:

1. Tried to merge via SharePoint Designer. I stuck when I need to connect new page to Linked Source - I can't even choose data source
2. this option is for modern SharePoint, as I understood: http://www.boostsolutions.com/blog/how-to-integrate-multiple-sharepoint-lists-into-one-list/
3. This option uses Content Query Web Part. I couldn't find one in my SharePoint https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/when-to-use-the-content-query-web-part-or-the-content-search-web-part-in-sharepoint-346a0f48-38de-409b-8a58-3bdca1768929

Is there another way to merge several lists?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer for my issue.
The easiest way is to create [Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr9UU.png)

1. Create recurrence - schedule your task
2. Use Get items - the items you'd like to move. In this action you should use advanced settings and choose filtering you wanna apply on your data (I've decieded that I need to copy every item that was created later than January 2021) - [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y67bW.png). More about OData filters [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169248(v=nav.90).aspx).
3. Fill in next step (applied to all) - [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOU50.png)
4. copy this Flow for every list you need to combine into one list

That's all actually. I created one more flow but this one is much easier.
I hope it'll help

In addition, here is the link for wonderful YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLBohC1Rw00) where you can learn how to automate modification of combined list